Induced Electric field in metasurface
In CST Microwave Studio, for metasurface simulation, the defined electric field for the incident linearly polarized plane wave is 1 V/m. However, the induced electric field for the unit cell of the metasurface is found to be $10^6$ V/m. How can one get this much high induced field from a minimal external electric field amplitude?

sharp edges and corners.
